# Page transition

Tags: javascript, css, transition, onbeforeunload

I'm trying to apply a page transition. It basically consists in adding a class to a div and run the transition before page unload. This is what I have.
https://codepen.io/bcrvlh/pen/mddOQLx

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(event) { 
$("a").click(function(){
$("bottom-layer").addClass("active");});
});
```

can you give me a help? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<a href="#">click</a>
<div id="bottom-layer" class="bottom-layer"></div>
```

**JS**

```
window.onload = function(){
  let element = document.getElementById("bottom-layer");
  element.classList.add("active");
};
```

With jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#bottom-layer').addClass('active');
})
```

If you want it to happen before page unloads you should create a function for each click and set a timeout for example:

**Html**

```
<a onclick = "navigate('place-href-here')"></a>
```

**JS**

```
function navigate(href-received-as-argument){
  let element = document.getElementById("bottom-layer");
  element.classList.add("active");
  setTimeout(function() {
   window.location.href = href-received-as-argument;
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: I tried that and it works but only on page load and not before it unloads :/ 
I make this change 
`window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(event) { 
let element = document.getElementById("bottom-layer"); element.classList.add("active");
});`
and now it works but now I still need to delay the page unload for 0.7s so the transitions can be visible